# Authentication for Videoview in android

Tags: android

I'm using a **Videoview** to play http video.That Http video url needs **Authentication**.

So please let me know how authentication can be set to the VideoView?If not is there any other alternative for viewing authenticated video.?

Thanks & Regards,
Sree Harsha .

Answer (score 7):

There is a hidden method in VideoView that allows setting HTTP headers. You can use reflection to access it. But it will only help if the server supports basic authentication

```
Method setVideoURIMethod = videoView.getClass().getMethod("setVideoURI", Uri.class, Map.class);
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
final String cred = login + ":" + pwd;
final String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeBytes(cred.getBytes("UTF-8"));
params.put("Authorization", auth);
setVideoURIMethod.invoke(videoView, uri, params);
```

Of course since this is undocumented API it is not guaranteed to work properly, you should handle exceptions and have a fallback plan.

Comment: setvideoURI is now public as of api 22 :)

Answer (score 1):

First you should know what kind of authentication is required by this server: http://unixpapa.com/auth/index.html

Second, depending of auth type, you should provide auth parameters (username/password) inside the URL. Usually this will be accepted (but not necessatilly, you should test): `http://username:password@www.yourhostname.com/whatever`

This are basic, http-style authentications. Modern sites use other options such as OpenID and OAuth. This are a bit harder to implement.

Anyhow, you should know type type of authentication, before you start looking for solution.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested,But it's not working and the same suggestion working for my iphone team.I tested in Galaxy 3.I also checked the link like "http://username:password@www.yourhostname.com/whatever" in browser ,again it is promoting a message regarding credentials. Is it a device bug?Any suggestions invited..

Comment: What kind of authentication is this website using?

Comment: Did you mean Apache's ".htaccess" file? This is just a file where Apache configuration is stored: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: yes it is apache HTacess file.So can we do anything from our side?

Comment: The only way for VideoView to authenticate is to have URL that has embedded username/pass, like this: `http://username:password@www.yourhostname.com/whatever`. So you need to set Apache to accept such authentication. I'm not expert on Apache so can't help you with this.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Any ways i made my client to remove username passwords for videos .... :)

Answer (score 0):

The reflection API access to the setViewUri(Uri, Map) worked for me.

I guess a safer alternative is to use the [MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Context, Uri, Map)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29):

A risk of using the reflection API is that the API might disappear in a future release...