# Stream authenticated Video with MediaPlayer on Android

Tags: android

I’m trying to stream & play the Videos  from the SharePoint server URL  having basic auth **(username/password)**  in my Android device `browser / Media Player /VideoView`
But I’m getting

**the error**

```
 sorry this video can’t be played.
```

Also auth parameters (username/password) inside the URL is not working  (eg: http://username:password@www.hostname.com/test.mp4 )

But I can download and play it fine using the Android HTTP download class with authentication.

Can anybody suggest how  authentication can be set to the VideoView  class for streaming video

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Bugdr0id see my answer. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is still looking for answer Here is a way to set authentication in videoview.

```
Map<String, String> header= new HashMap<String, String>(1);
final String cred = "your_username" + ":" + "your_password";
final String auth = "Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString(cred.getBytes(),Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP);
header.put("Authorization", auth);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("your url"),header);
videoView.start();
```

but for lower api setVdeoUri method is hidden. You can see  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16787575/2579281)

and if you are using [Google ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) you will have to set data source like this.

```
    final String cred = "username" + ":" + "password";
    final String auth = "Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString(cred.getBytes(),Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP);
    DefaultHttpDataSource dataSource = new DefaultHttpDataSource(userAgent, null);
    dataSource.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
    dataSource.setRequestProperty("Accept", "...");
```

Answer (score 2):

My version with DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory

```
private fun buildMediaSource(url: String): MediaSource {
    val uri = Uri.parse(url)
    val auth =
        "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(uri.userInfo?.toByteArray(), URL_SAFE or NO_WRAP)
    val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-codelab").apply {
        defaultRequestProperties.set("Authorization", auth)
        defaultRequestProperties.set("Accept", "...")
    }
    return ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri)
}
```