# How to resolve NullPointerException on HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am developing an Android application, using ExoPlayer for video playback, Glide for image display, and a download library for file download, and they all have NullPointerException related to HttpURLConnection, I'm sure the link used is available.

The magic is, I just follow these library's The method described in the official documentation loads the data normally, and this error occurs from time to time, and the three libraries may not throw NullPointerException at the same time, and I don't even know how to reproduce this problem.

This is the error thrown by ExoPlayer, which prevents the video from loading:

```
E/LoadTask: Unexpected exception loading stream
      java.lang.NullPointerException: wrapped.getHeaderField(key) must not be null
        at com.android.tools.appinspection.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(TrackedHttpURLConnection.kt:317)
        at com.android.tools.appinspection.network.httpurl.HttpsURLConnectionWrapper.getHeaderField(HttpsURLConnectionWrapper.kt:182)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.isCompressed(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:829)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:413)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1009)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

The video playback part of the code is as follows:

```kotlin
            val factory = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
                DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
            )
            val mediaSource = arrayListOf<MediaSource>(
                factory.createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(video.base_url)),
                factory.createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(audio.base_url))
            )
            val media = MergingMediaSource(true, *mediaSource.toTypedArray())
            ViewModel.getPlayer()?.let { player ->
                player.setMediaSource(media)
                player.prepare()
            }
```

And this is the error thrown by Aria, which cause software to crash:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-5-thread-2
    Process: io.github.sgpublic.bilidownload, PID: 22400
    java.lang.NullPointerException: wrapped.getRequestProperty(field) must not be null
        at com.android.tools.appinspection.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.getRequestProperty(TrackedHttpURLConnection.kt:235)
        at com.android.tools.appinspection.network.httpurl.HttpsURLConnectionWrapper.getRequestProperty(HttpsURLConnectionWrapper.kt:274)
        at com.arialyy.aria.http.ConnectionHelp.setConnectParam(ConnectionHelp.java:146)
        at com.arialyy.aria.http.download.HttpDFileInfoTask.run(HttpDFileInfoTask.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I have tried Invalidate and Restart, and even uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio completely, but the problem still cannot be solved, so what is the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906749/stream-authenticated-video-with-mediaplayer-on-android

Comment: just now I got the same error with exoplayer I even change wifi but it didn't work. and it disappeared when I reinstall the app. strange~.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the related entry, and to sum it up this is [a bug in the TrackedHttpURLConnection implementation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/219572925), the fix will be capped around mid-late March.

Update: (Mar 4, 2022 07:09AM)

```
Thank you for your patience while our engineering team worked to resolve this issue. A fix for this issue is now available in:

Android Studio Dolphin Canary 5 (2021.3.1.5)
Android Gradle Plugin 7.3.0-alpha05
We encourage you to try the latest update.

If you notice further issues or have questions, please file a new bug report.

Thank you for taking the time to submit feedback — we really appreciate it!
```