# How to solve java.lang.NullPointerException: wrapped.contentEncoding must not be null?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, http, android-volley

The issue is I try to call endpoint through mobile apps which are android apps that I developed from android studio. at backend site is no exception appear. but then at logcat android showing up the error below:

```
E/Volley: [354] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: wrapped.contentEncoding must not be null
java.lang.NullPointerException: wrapped.contentEncoding must not be null
    at com.android.tools.appinspection.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.getContentEncoding(TrackedHttpURLConnection.kt:177)
    at com.android.tools.appinspection.network.httpurl.HttpURLConnectionWrapper.getContentEncoding(HttpURLConnectionWrapper.kt:127)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.entityFromConnection(HurlStack.java:160)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:120)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
```

how to solve this issue? really appreciate your guys help

Comment: `(TrackedHttpURLConnection.kt:177)`

Comment: Hi, please give a reasonable answer

Comment: I'm having the same issue through Glide.

Comment: Seems to be related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284785/how-to-resolve-nullpointerexception-on-httpurlconnection