# Convert CookieStore to String: pb with encode/decode value

Tags: java, javascript, android, node.js, cookies

I have my cookies in a CookieStore Object, but to stream a video I need to convert my CookieStore to a String, but my API in NodeJS (using express, cookie-parser and passport-local) never recognizes the value of the cookie, whenever I try to encode/decode it before. I think it's a stupid problem just I'm not really good in HTTP Headers so I'm doing it wrong.

There is the code:

```
Method setVideoURIMethod = videovvw.getClass().getMethod("setVideoURI", Uri.class, Map.class);
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
params.put("Cookie", ARequestAPI.getCookieString());
setVideoURIMethod.invoke(videovvw, uri[0], params);
```

I had the code from here so normally it should work perfectly: [Authentication for Videoview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898271/authentication-for-videoview-in-android)

I think the problem comes from "`ARequest.getCookieString()`":

```
protected static CookieStore _cookies = null;
...
...
...
public static String getCookieString() {
    String cookieString = "";
    Log.v("Debug", _cookies.toString());
    for (Cookie cookie : _cookies.getCookies()) {
        try {
            Log.v("Debug", "Decode: " + URLDecoder.decode(cookie.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            Log.v("Debug", "Encode: " + URLEncoder.encode(cookie.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        cookieString += cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue()+ ";";
    }
    return cookieString;
}
```

The display in LogCat:

> [image: LogCat]

And the log on my API:
When I do a request using CookieStore:

```
{ 'connect.sid': 's:NUTf8t9o8cepR1yYItMexMxy.WFv/ZlktryfpVZHweVozabW1US4UBvGlWxQR7G7Aamc' }
```

When I do the request with my function which convert the CookieStore to a String:

```
{ 'connect.sid': 's:AZXpZmQGX7eJgej9hVA1qaAk.7vWP756Flwbte/qxBRcLOhl/CXMlVO3HVvmsvsEBpzA' }
```

I tried all the options, even `encode(decode())`, ... but it is never a good one on my API.
The weird thing is that I tried to decode `'s%3ANUTf...'` (so `cookie.getValue()`) with the javascript function "`decodeURIComponent()`" and I found exactly `'s:NUTf8t9o8cepR1yYItMexMxy.WFv/ZlktryfpVZHweVozabW1US4UBvGlWxQR7G7Aamc'`, so my cookie is good, but I think I'm doing something wrong on the encode/decode part.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: After many tests, I saw that on the API the value for the cookie is always the same, whenever I use URLDecoder.decode(), URLDecoder.decode() or event directly cookie.getValue(), the only time I get the right value is when I "choose/write" the value myself like "totoauzoo" for example with this wring I get exactly the same value on the API. But it's not working with my old cookie value like "s:DMCBao7zeS9B2jwIfeQoDZtl.3XPIYIm7y2Bz9/o468v4wxvFZmjDrc6hKk4ty89sIX4".

Edit2: I probably found what is wrong, I get that on the API:

request with HttpGet and CookieStore:

```
headers { host: 'xxx',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive',
  'user-agent': 'Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)',
  cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3AGRGciNxOcR4BXHrUG8PikHMX.MyWa6vjW%2BBlcUaaCHHendqc7DEK4aoNFDzm5aabOkDM',
  cookie2: '$Version=1' }
cookies { 'connect.sid': 's:GRGciNxOcR4BXHrUG8PikHMX.MyWa6vjW+BlcUaaCHHendqc7DEK4aoNFDzm5aabOkDM' }
```

request with setVideoURI:

headers { host: 'xxx',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3AKWKdcuXqUpzBIMv0sOGpPxqM.xb14kPsGKvn%2Fv%2BVcfUDzxWsye8QdJfuQgonNocsX3k8',
  'user-agent': 'stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.1.2)',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate' }
cookies { 'connect.sid': 's:KWKdcuXqUpzBIMv0sOGpPxqM.xb14kPsGKvn/v+VcfUDzxWsye8QdJfuQgonNocsX3k8' }

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest inspecting the network traffic itself. 
Cookies are nothing else than HTTP headers ...

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: name=value
Set-Cookie: name2=value2; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT
```

or

```
GET /spec.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Cookie: name=value; name2=value2
Accept: */*
```

I'm not familiar with the classes you are using to set the cookies, but I would inspect two places:

**1:**

```
params.put("Cookie", ARequestAPI.getCookieString());
```

Is this call setting the headers or are you setting POST parameters? This should be visible in the network traffic. What are *params*? Headers, query string?

**2:**

```
ARequestAPI.getCookieString()
```

Is the output of this function in correct cookie value format, or what is it?

Most probably in one of those places lies the error.

Comment: How I can inspect the network traffic? so for 1) I'm setting that: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setVideoURI%28android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29 and for 2) I more sure it's correctly formated because i did the function by myself but the name of the cookie is good on the API, just the value is wrong.

Comment: Well, it's working perfectly with charlesproxy, my cookie is the good one but that doesn't help me for my problem because it has to work without it :/

Comment: Well after removed CharlesProxy it worked again, so I restart my computer and my server, still working, create an apk and try it on my phone, still good. I really don't know was wrong, but now it seen working. Thanks to you.

Comment: You have hit the magic restart key on your machine, happens all the time ;)